# How to make a fairly simple 5- star rating system?

Tags: php, sql

I am making it so people may download songs on my site, and I want there to be a rating system with 5-stars too tell which is best, Can someone help?
I would like it to be in database something like user_id, rating then the php sorts out the algorithim and what not shows images/stars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice tutorial that teaches you how to do this:

http://webtint.net/tutorials/5-star-rating-system-in-php-mysql-and-jquery/

Comment: The link appears to be dead :(

Answer (score 3):

Please see following Code:
http://www.phptoys.com/e107_plugins/content/content.php?content.75
  http://2008.gr0w.com/articles/code/php_5_star_rating_system_using_hreview/

Answer (score 2):

Add to your song table two columns:

- int hits
- float rating

When user rates a song fetch it's rating and hits and just do:

```
rating = ( hits * rating + userRating ) / (hits + 1)
hits = hits + 1
```

When you display stars, parse that `rating` to integer and you will get number of not-grayed stars to display.

Answer (score 1):

Write to database rating from 1 to 5
Than doing smth like this:

```
SELECT SUM(rating)/COUNT(rating) FROM rating WHERE rating_for_id = INT
```